# Adding invoices inside the acumatica

Tags: spring, spring-boot, acumatica, invoice, acumatica-kb

I have a requirement to integrate invoices into Acumatica and subsequently create a REST endpoint using Spring Boot to retrieve details of unpaid invoices. However, I am entirely unfamiliar with Acumatica, and this software is new to me. I have no knowledge of the process involved in achieving this task. If anyone could offer any assistance, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this first: https://www.acumatica.com/media/2020/02/AcumaticaERP_IntegrationDevelopmentGuide.pdf

The interesting part is the Working with the Contract-Based REST API section.